# How to hide text besides of awesome font icon

Tags: jquery, html, css

I used awesome font and add text left of the icon. I want to hide the text when it will be browsed in the smaller browser. But I don't understand how to point that text using css. My code is:

```
<button class="slideout-menu-toggle"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i> Menu</button>
```

I want to hide the word `Menu` when it will be browsed in smaller device. Is there any way to determine the word. I tried add `<span>` in the menu but text gets break and display in new line.

Answer (score 4):

You can't point at text with CSS, only elements.

1. Wrap the text in a `<span>`
2. Find the CSS that triggers the line break on the span you tried before and fix it
3. Restyle the span to hide the text (e.g. by resizing it and setting `overflow: hidden`) when the media query matches the window width you want

Comment: Is it possible by js?

Comment: Only by generating the elements you need so that you can target them with CSS. Getting it right in the first place is a much better bet.

Comment: If you hide the text inside the button, it (the button) will no longer have an [accessible name](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/terms#def_accessible_name). You can fix it by adding `aria-label="Menu"`.

Answer (score 0):

try this, I added a span and it didn't break the text.

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    .slideout-menu-toggle > span{
        display:none;
    }
}
```

```html
<button class="slideout-menu-toggle"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i> <span>Menu</span></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Display:none hides the text from screen readers too. Instead use

```
{
text-indent: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    }
```

See this [article](http://www.zeldman.com/2012/03/01/replacing-the-9999px-hack-new-image-replacement/)

Comment: yes I followed this way earlier, but couldn't fix because I did not add `white-space: nowrap;`. However, this answer helped me.